# I restarted migration assistant, do I need to delete data from the first transfer?

Tags: migration-assistant

I recently bought a new Mac, and was using the migration assistant to transfer all the stuff from my old Mac. I forgot to plug one of the computers in though, so the transfer got stopped (and wouldn't start again) when it died. I just set it up to restart, with both of them plugged in. It has about 9 hours remaining (out of 12).

My question is... is there going to be data on the harddrive somewhere from the first (failed) transfer? I'd hate to already be cluttering up a new computer. If the data is there somewhere, how do I go about deleting it?

Thanks!